# How do i get access to getters for Object o

Tags: java, oop, object, equals

My question is how do i gain access to my getters for the object o. It is an instance of BankTransaction but when i try to for example use o.getSender() I recieve an error.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this instanceof BankTransaction && o instanceof BankTransaction) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Check which specific class the object instantiates and cast it to that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the first part down. Just add a cast if `o` is of the right type.

```
if (o instanceof BankTransaction) {
    BankTransaction bt = (BankTransaction) o;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Mate thank you so much!! especially for such a quick response to my question! i really appreciate your time. have a fantastic day! cheers!!

Comment: It is probably a good idea to help the OP get in the habit of minimizing block nesting by using `if (! o instanceof BankTransaction) { return false; } ...`